# How to save all pictures from picamera directly to an USB-Stick?

Tags: python, picamera

I am new to Python and made a simple project with my raspberry pi 4, where the picamera takes pictures via button and saves them. Until now the pictures are saved in the home-directory, but I want them to be saved on an USB-Stick.

I have created a target folder `/mnt/mydisk` to be the mount point of the storage device, and still get an Error everytime I shoot a picture. Can anyone help?

This is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from gpiozero import Button
import picamera
import time

b=Button(2) 
b2=Button(23)
pc=picamera.PiCamera()
running = True
pc.rotation=180 

def picture():
    timestamp=datetime.now() 
    pc.capture('/media/pi/INTENSO/pic'+str(timestamp)+'.jpg')

def close():
    pc.stop_preview()
    running = False
    pc.close()

pc.start_preview() 
b.when_pressed=picture
b2.when_pressed=close
```

I also tried it with the link to `/mnt/mydisk, /dev/sda1` and none of them work..

Comment: Might it just be a permission problem, i.e. the user trying to save the image not having write permission on the USB-drive? How do you mount the external drive, who is the owner?

Comment: Hi Fiximan, i am the owner (pi) and have permission to view, change and access the usb-stick. Is writing permission included in these? And i mounted it with the steps from the official raspberry doc (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/external-storage.md). I had PermissionError indeed, but when adding the 'pc.close()' the Error changed to an OSError, do you know how this can be solved?

Comment: How do you mount it? Could you add the results of `mount` and `ls -l /mnt` to the question? Maybe you once mount it as user `pi` and once as `root`.

Comment: Please move the output here and do not make it an answer. Reduce it to lines that contain your USB - the output of `mount` tells me you have only mounted it at `/media/pi/INTENSO` and not at `/mnt/mydisk`. The latter is currently just a directory owned by `root`, thus no write permissions for `pi`.